# changing scene automatically after the progressbar loading is complete is complete

Tags: javafx, initialization, fxml, scene

i am working on a simple javafx banking app for practise. I have created a starting scene that basically has a progress bar.i have been lloking for way to change the scene to something like a login scene lets say, after the progress bar is full.
But since i have written the code to control the progress bar in the Controllers initialize method trying to access the stage gives me Nullpointer exception. any idea how i can acieve this using fxml

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to do this: [Displays a JavaFX splash page for an intensive startup task with progress monitoring](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/2305098).  I'm not sure why you need a progress bar in the first place and "what after loading is complete" means.  What is loading? How is it being loaded? On what thread is it loading?

Comment: Thanks that helped